# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms' (v. 8.1.0)

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I just tried to update `play-services-analytics` from `7.5.0` to `8.1.0` and just changed the version number in gradle. And what I got:

```
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

`rebuild` and `clean` don't help. I also tried to delete the folder with this library, no effect. If I change the number to `7.8.0` (or back to `7.5.0`) it also works well, but not with `8.1.0`

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likelay you have another library that depends on version 7.5.0. Try to run

```
gradlew :you_project_name:dependancies
```

To figure it out.