# More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: java, android

I have found lots of posts about this question ,but non of them worked for me.Here is my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*********"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile files('libs/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'

}
```

I can't figure out where there the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms' (v. 8.1.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831296/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-v-8-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to the latest `play-services` library:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

---

In any case, you should always try to only add the dependencies you will need for example:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0
```

Check the [bottom of the following link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) to see more about the decoupled dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize as a tree:

```
gradle -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Or on Windows, use `gradlew`

```
gradlew -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Example output:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.6
+--- in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.10
+--- com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3
+--- com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3
+--- org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+ -> 6.5.87
+--- project :yourProject
|    +--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5
|    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- project :facebook
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1 -> 22.2.0
```

To avoid duplicates, add `exclude` in each project `build.gradle`

```
compile('com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+')
        {
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
```

This is sampled from: [gradle - library duplicates in dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the same support version for your support libraries (appcompat, cardview, recyclerview)
Also you can try updating fresco to the current version (0.11.0) to check if that solves the problem.
Also avoid using '+' in the dependencies because it's simply a bad practice and can lead to unexpected behaviours.